# send catch block to $error variable

Tags: powershell

I have a script which tests several things at startup e.g if some networkdrives still need to be mapped. it will then map it if it needs to.

Sometimes there occurs an error like this.

```
In \\server\powershell$\Powershell-Scripts\_DVLP\LogonScript.ps1:57 
Zeichen:9
+         $Map.MapNetworkDrive($_.letter,$_.path,$false)
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation
```

I get that error as an e-mail attachment by a file which is generated by simply exporting the `$error` variable in to a file

```
$error |out-file C:\myfile.txt -force
```

as you can see, the error is not very helpful because I don't see the drive letter in there. So I want to wrap my .mapnetworkdrive into a Try/Catch Block.

```
Try {...} 
Catch {
    $failedletter= $_.letter
    $failedpath = $_.path
    $export = $failedletter + $failedpath + $_.exception.message #send this to $error variable
}
```

my question now is, if I can send a whole Catch Block (or parts of it) to the `$error` variable so I don't have to make my logging more complex. is there any way to send things to the error variable?

can I simply do `$error += $export`? is it then two times in the $error variable? it should only be in there once

Comment: I would expand the error using `$error | fl * -Force` and pipe the result to your `out-file`

Comment: @jisaak the question is more like, how can I get additional stuff (see $failedletter and $failedpath) to the error variable, because this variables behaviour is to fill itself with error information. I don't know how to do it without breaking anything or get error information about 1 error twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you invoke the `Get-Member` cmdlet on a `ErrorRecord` you will see, that you are only able to set the `ErrorDetails`:

```
Name                  MemberType     Definition                                                                                                                                            
----                  ----------     ----------                                                                                                                                            
Equals                Method         bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                                                                                        
GetHashCode           Method         int GetHashCode()                                                                                                                                     
GetObjectData         Method         void GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context), void ISerializable....
GetType               Method         type GetType()                                                                                                                                        
ToString              Method         string ToString()                                                                                                                                     
CategoryInfo          Property       System.Management.Automation.ErrorCategoryInfo CategoryInfo {get;}                                                                                    
ErrorDetails          Property       System.Management.Automation.ErrorDetails ErrorDetails {get;set;}                                                                                     
Exception             Property       System.Exception Exception {get;}                                                                                                                     
FullyQualifiedErrorId Property       string FullyQualifiedErrorId {get;}                                                                                                                   
InvocationInfo        Property       System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo InvocationInfo {get;}                                                                                     
PipelineIterationInfo Property       System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection[int] PipelineIterationInfo {get;}                                                                   
ScriptStackTrace      Property       string ScriptStackTrace {get;}                                                                                                                        
TargetObject          Property       System.Object TargetObject {get;}                                                                                                                     
PSMessageDetails      ScriptProperty System.Object PSMessageDetails {get=& { Set-StrictMode -Version 1; $this.Exception.InnerException.PSMessageDetails };}
```

So you could do something like:

```
Try {...} 
catch {
    $_.ErrorDetails += ('Letter: {0} Path: {1}' -f $_.letter, $_.path)
    throw $_
}
```